# Is an embedding of any group into itself always an automorphism?

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory

I came across a question in chapter-8 The power of homomorphism  (Visual group theory Book) which says that:

Is an embedding of any group into itself always an automorphism? 
(Hint is that It is true as long as group is finite,When group is infinite consider the function $\phi$: $\mathbb Z$$\rightarrow$$\mathbb Z$ by $\phi(n)$=$2n$.)

I can't understand the hint,where does the above function violates being an automorphism.

Comment: An automorphism is, by definition, a bijection.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As Mike Miller said in his comment, an automorphism is by definition a homomorphism that is also a bijection from the group $G$ to itself.

$\mathbb{Z}$ is an infinite group, and $\phi(n) = 2n$ is an embedding (i.e., a homomorphic injection) from $\mathbb{Z}$ into itself.  But $\phi$ is *not* a bijection, because it is *not* surjective.  To see this, consider $3 \in \mathbb{Z}$.  What is being mapped to $3$ under $\phi$?  If the map *was* surjective, then every element of the codomain $\mathbb{Z}$ must have something from the domain $\mathbb{Z}$ that is being mapped to it.

But by the definition of the map $\phi(n) = 2n$, the element being mapped to $3$ should be $\frac{3}{2}$ since $2(\frac{3}{2}) = 3$. But $\frac{3}{2}$ is not in the domain $\mathbb{Z}$ since it is a rational number but not an integer.  So nothing in the domain is being mapped to $3$ if we are considering the map $\phi: \mathbb{Z} \to \mathbb{Z}$ with domain $\mathbb{Z}$.  The same argument is true for any odd integer in the codomain $\mathbb{Z}$, not just the number $3$.

However, if the group (or any set) you are dealing with is *finite*, and you have an injection from the group to itself, the same map is also always automatically a surjection, as well, and hence a bijection.  Do you understand why this is?

Comment: probably because in a finite set if we have an injection ensures that the two sets have same no. of elements and hence every element in image is ensured it has pre-image,but such is not the case with infinite sets because to check onto when they are 1-1 we need to know cardinalities of two sets are equal which in infinite case we can only know if they have 1-1 correspondence.

Comment: @WantTobeAbstract You are completely correct in the case of finite sets.  But I am a little confused by what you said about the infinite sets.  If we have a particular map that is 1-1 between two infinite sets, the map is not necessarily a bijection exactly because of the property of infinite sets where a *proper subset* of the infinite set can have the same cardinality as the infinite set.  As an example, $\{1,3,5,7,9,\cdots \}$ has the same cardinality as $\{1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,\cdots \}$, even though one is a proper subset of the other.

Comment: @WantTobeAbstract So you can have a 1-1 map between two infinite sets (even if they both have the same cardinality), but it would not be onto if the image of the map is a strict subset of the codomain, which *can* happen in the case of infinite sets (but cannot happen in the case of finite sets, as you said).  But, to be clear, just because a particular 1-1 map is not necessarily bijective, does not mean there doesn't exist a bijection between the two sets.  As is the case of $\mathbb{Z}$ with itself.  Clearly, the identity map is a bijection of $\mathbb{Z}$ with itself.

Comment: @WantTobeAbstract But we can find a different map, which is the one you discussed sending $n$ to $2n$, which is injective, but not surjective.

Comment: thanks for the clarification.

Comment: @WantTobeAbstract You're welcome!